# Buscar y editar en array asociativa multidimensional

Tags: php, mysql

les comento que estoy diseñando un pequeño carrito de compras y me encontré con un problema.

Estoy usando sesiones para gestionar el carrito de compra, de modo que si el usario añade algo al carro el codigo php lo procesa de esta manera:

```
$_SESSION["carrito"][]=array('id_producto'=>$id_producto,'cantidad'=>$cantidad,'parametro1'=>$parametro1);
```

Esto me devuelve un array como esta:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id_producto"]=> int(2) ["cantidad"]=> int(2) ["parametro1"]=> int(7) } [1]=> array(5) { ["id_producto"]=> int(5) ["cantidad"]=> int(5) ["parametro1"]=> int(7) } }
```

El problema surge cuando el usuario agrega el mismo producto, por ejemplo, el producto con id 1 ya cuenta con 2 unidades añadidas al carro. Si el usuario añade 2 mas del mismo producto, de que manera puedo sumar la cantidad nueva a esa misma array? es decir, que no me añada un array nuevo con el mismo producto y otra cantidad, si no que modifique la que ya existe y lo sume a la cantidad.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que usa para agregar los productos?

Comment: $_SESSION["carrito"][]=array('id_producto'=>$id_producto,'cantidad'=>$cantidad,'parametro1'=>$parametro1,'parametro2'=>$parametro2,'parametro3'=>$parametro3);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era mas sencilla de lo que pensaba.

```
$i = 0; //indice para saber la posicion de el producto
foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $row) { //recorremos con foreach
    if ($row["id"] == $_GET['producto_id']) { //si el producto que se agrego ya existe
        $nueva = $_SESSION["carrito"][$i]['cantidad'] + $_GET['cantidad'];
        //acá modificamos el array multidimensional pasando el valor nuevo de la variable $nueva, sabiendo su posición gracias al indice creado anteriormente ($i)
        $_SESSION["carrito"][$i]['cantidad'] = $nueva;
    }
    $i++;
}
```